# function return to a variable in utility.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.

I need to do the following code in utility.php which is a custom library.

```
class Utility{
public $x=test("123");
public function test($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
echo $x;
}
```

Thanks in advance
This is showing syntax error.

Comment: probably not in here.(works fine on mine) and whats `utility.php` ?? remove `public` above code

Comment: @Dead Man Alive it is a file inside my libraries

Comment: remove `public` key from above code and try

Comment: @raru if this is a library why are you printing anything outside function. tell us what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
class Utility
{
    public $x;

    public function __construct($name = 'default name')
    {
        $this->x = $this->test($name);
    }

    public function test($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Then in controller you would go with

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($name = null)
    {
        $this->load->library('utility', [$name]);

        echo $this->utility->x;
    }
}
```